# Calculating etale cohomology of Picard stack

Tags: algebraic-geometry, etale-cohomology, algebraic-stacks

I would like to try to calculate say $H_{\acute{e}tale}^*(B\mathbb{G}_{m, k}, \mathbb{Z}/p)$. Intuitively, since $B\mathbb{G}_m$ classifies line bundles, its topological analogue should be $\mathbb{CP}^{\infty}$, and so I expect the cohomology to be $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}[x], |x| = 2$, but i'm not entirely sure how to go about doing this calculation.

As a stack $B\mathbb{G}_m$ is given by $[*/\mathbb{G}_m]$, but it isn't clear to me how to provide an $\acute{e}$tale cover that would provide a reasonable Čech cohomology calculation.

Comment: Are you working over an algebraically closed field ? Can you use the spectral sequence $E_1^{ij}=H^j(\mathbb{G}_{m,k}^i,\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})\Rightarrow H^{i+j}(B\mathbb{G}_{m,k},\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})$ ?

Comment: @Roland where exactly does that spectral sequence come from and what is $\mathbb{G}_m^i$?

Comment: I meant $\mathbb{G}_m^i=\mathbb{G}_m\times...\times\mathbb{G}_m$ the $i$-fold product over $k$. Then $B\mathbb{G}_m$ can be realized as the simplicial scheme $\mathbb{G}_m^2\rightarrow\mathbb{G}_m\rightarrow *$. Then this is the spectral sequence associated to this simplicial scheme.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3217498/making-h-mathbfp-infty-lim-h-mathbfpn-kt-precise-using-stacks for an answer using that $B\mathbf{G}_m$ is in some sense the limit of $\mathbf{P}^n$.