# Making $H^*(\mathbf{P}^\infty)=\lim H^*(\mathbf{P}^n)=k[t]$ precise using stacks

Tags: algebraic-geometry, homology-cohomology, etale-cohomology, algebraic-stacks

The stack $B\mathbf{G}_m$, i.e. morally $\mathbf{P}^\infty$, has (etale) cohomology $\mathbf{Q}_\ell[t]$.

The scheme $\mathbf{P}^n$ has cohomology $\mathbf{Q}_\ell[t]/t^n$.

In algebraic topology, the first fact follows immediately from (the proof of) the second, using the CW complex decomposition of $\mathbf{CP}^\infty$.

Is there a sense in which $B\mathbf{G}_m=\lim\mathbf{P}^n$ as stacks, and if so does this allow us to compute its cohomology?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a classic computation that one can do, for any $\mathrm{GL}_n$, essentially using the natural map $\mathrm{Grass}_n(h)\to B\mathrm{GL}_n$ defined by the universal quotient. It's shown with spectacular clarity in Lemma 2.3.1 of Kai Behrend's article [*The Lefschetz trace formula for algebraic stacks*](https://eudml.org/doc/144097). Specifically, you are interested in the subsequent corollary when $n=1$.

For $\mathbb{G}_m$ what this essentially means that is that for all $i\geqslant 0$ you have a natural map $\mathbb{P}^n\to B\mathbb{G}_m$ defined by the universal quotient which induces a map

$$H^i(B\mathbb{G}_m,\mathbb{Q}_\ell)\to H^i(\mathbb{P}^n_k,\mathbb{Q}_\ell)$$

which is an isomorphism for $i\leqslant 2(n-1)$. One then gets the desired result by passing to the limit in $i$.